# Calling external services in scala code with dependencies

Tags: web-services, scala, design-patterns, io, pattern-matching

I am facing a major issue with my design at this juncture. My method is trying to accomplish the follows:

1. Insert the passed in object into the database.
2. Get the autoincremented id from the insert and use it to call webservice1 along with the object.
3. Get the result from webservice1 and call webservice2 with the original object and some response from webservice1.
4. Combine the results from webservice1 and 2 and write it into the database.
5. Get the resulting autoincremented id from the last insert and call webservice3 with the original object that would eventually result into the success or failure of the operation.

I want to design this in a flexible manner since the requirements are in a flux and I do not want to keep on modifying my logic based on any changing. I do realize some amount of change is inevitable but I would like to minimize the damage and respect the open-closed principle.

My initial take was as follows:

```
def complexOperation(someObject:T) = 
   dbService.insertIntoDb(someObject) match {
     case Left(e:Exception) => Left(e)
     case Right(id:Int) => webService.callWebService1(id,someObject) match {
        case Left(e:Exception) => Left(e)
        case Right(r:SomeResponse1) => webService.callWebservice2(r,someObject) match {
          case Left(e:Exception) => webService.rollbackService1();Left(e)
          case Right(context:ResponseContext) => dbService.insertContextIntoDb(context) match {
            case Left(e:Exception) => Left(e)
            case Right(id:Int) => webService.callWebservice3(id,someObject) match {
               case Left(e:Exception) => webService.rollbackService3();Left(e)
               case Right(r:Response) => Right(r)
            }
          }
        } 
     }
```

As you can see, this is a tangled mess. I can neither unit test it, nor extend it nor very easily debug it if things spiral out of control. This code serves its purpose but it will be great to get some ideas on how I should refactor it to make the lives of the people who inherit my code a little more easier.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at [scala.util.Try](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/rc/index.html#scala.util.Try). It's available in Scala 2.10, which may or may not be available to you as an option, but the idea of it is perfect for your scenario.

What you have in your code example is what I like calling the "pyramid" of nesting. The best solution to this is to use flat-mapping wherever you can. But obviously that's an issue when you have stuff like `Either[Exception, Result]` at every step. That's where `Try` comes in. `Try[T]` is essentially a replacement for `Either[Exception, T]`, and it comes with all of the `flatMap`-ing goodness that you need.

Assuming you can either change the return type of those `webService` calls, or provide some implicit conversion from `Either[Exception, Result]` to `Try[Result]`, your code block would become something more like...

```
for {
    id <- dbService.insertIntoDb(someObject)
    r <- webService.callWebService1(id,someObject)
    context <- webService.callWebservice2(r,someObject)
    id2 <- dbService.insertContextIntoDb(context)
    response <- webService.callWebservice3(id,someObject).recoverWith {
        case e: Exception => webService.rollbackService3(); Failure(e)
    }
} yield response
```

Lift has a similar mechanism in [net.liftweb.common.Box](http://scala-tools.org/mvnsites/liftweb-2.4/#net.liftweb.common.Box). It's like `Option`, but with a container for Exceptions too.

**edit:** It looks like you can use the `left` or `right` method of an `Either`, and it will let you use `flatMap`-ing almost exactly the way I described with `Try`. The only difference is that the end result is an `Either[Exception, Result]` instead of a `Try[Result]`. Check out [LeftProjection](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.Either%24%24LeftProjection) for details/examples.

Comment: Thanks Dylan. This is pretty fascinating stuff. Unfortunately, I am stuck with a 2.9.1 codebase that needs to be refactored. Is there an idiomatic scala way to flatmap over the Either's which will in turn transparently bubble up the Exceptions at whichever generator the exception takes place, without continuing with the remainder of the computations? Also, is "recoverWith" a Try[T] property?

Comment: Last question first: `recoverWith` is indeed a `Try[T]` method. The docs I linked in my answer explain it pretty well. As for your first question, I don't know of any existing solution that operates directly on `Either`

Comment: @sc_ray I looked into it a bit more and have edited my answer. Hopefully this will work for you.

Comment: @sc_ray I'm sure you can use the `Try` implementation in Scala 2.9. Just copy the source somewhere in your source and you are done.

Comment: @Dylan - Perfect. This seems like a step in the right direction. I am marking this as the answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can use for comprehension to reduce the noise in the code.

Comment: Thanks. Speaking out of ignorance here, but how does the for comprehension handle the exceptions thrown?

Answer (score 2):

@Dylan had the right idea above. Let me see if I can help translate what you want to do into idiomatic Scala 2.9.1 code.

This version doesn't attempt any rollbacks:

```
// 1: No rollbacks, just returns the first exception in Left
def complexOperation1(someObject:T): Either[Exception, Response] = {      
  for {
    id       <- dbService.insertIntoDb(someObject).right
    r        <- webService.callWebService1(id, someObject).right
    context  <- webService.callWebservice2(idResp, someObject).right
    id2      <- dbService.insertContextIntoDb(context).right
    response <- webService.callWebservice3(id,someObject).right
  } yield response 
}
```

Now, let's try to do the rollbacks exactly as you had them above:

```
// 2: Rolls back all web services and returns first exception in Left       
def complexOperation1(someObject:T): Either[Exception, Response] = {      
  for {
    id       <- dbService.insertIntoDb(someObject).right
    r        <- webService.callWebService1(id, someObject).right
    context  <- webService.callWebservice2(idResp, someObject).left.map { e =>
                  webService.rollbackService1()
                  e
                }.right
    id2      <- dbService.insertContextIntoDb(context).right
    response <- webService.callWebservice3(id,someObject).left.map { e =>
                  webService.rollbackService3()
                  e
                }.right
  } yield response 
}
```

If you define a function which does the effect (the rollback) on the left, it get's a little cleaner and easier to test, for example:

```
// 3: Factor out the side-effect of doing the follbacks on Left
def rollbackIfLeft[T](f: => Either[Exception, T], r: => Unit): Either[Exception, T] = {
  val result = f
  result.left.foreach(_ => r) // do the rollback if any exception occured
  result
}

def complexOperation1(someObject:T): Either[Exception, Response] = {      
  for {
    id       <- dbService.insertIntoDb(someObject).right
    r        <- webService.callWebService1(id, someObject).right
    context  <- rollbackIfLeft(webService.callWebservice2(idResp, someObject),
                               webService.rollbackService1()).right
    id2      <- dbService.insertContextIntoDb(context).right
    response <- rollbackIfLeft(webService.callWebservice3(id,someObject),
                               webService.rollbackService3()).right
  } yield response 
}
```

You can try out `rollbackIfLeft` in the scala REPL to get a sense of it:

```
scala> rollbackIfLeft(Right(42), println("hey"))
res28: Either[Exception,Int] = Right(42)

scala> rollbackIfLeft(Left(new RuntimeException), println("ERROR!"))
ERROR!
res29: Either[Exception,Nothing] = Left(java.lang.RuntimeException)
```

Hope this helps!